# "Mechanical Draughtsman" in Russian

Tags: существительные

Please, could somebody tell me how to say in Russian "Mechanical Draughtsman"
It is a profession, trade.
In English means a person who draws and designs mechanical, structural or machine parts.
The drawing might be created on a drawing board or computer [ like AutoCad ]
Google gives "рисовальщика".

**Addendum**

In English language a Draughtsman, or better to say a senior or designer draughtsman is a person who designs and thereafter draws machine parts or structural constructions.
As his superior is a chief draughtsman, who might not be an engineer.
It is impossible just to draw machine parts, the draughtsman must be able to create something new which is talked in meeting together with an engineer or engineers. 
Once a draugtsman gets an idea what the customer wants, he is left on his own to design and to draw or to produce a drawing.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the translations could be:

- `Конструктор` or `Инженер-конструктор` (means a person who designs machine parts and draws technical images)
- `Чертежник` (means a person who draws technical images)

Comment: *Инженер-конструктор* sounds the most pertinent. And by the way, a highly-skilled worker who makes part prototypes used to be called *модельщик*.

Comment: _Инженер-конструктор_ implies formal engineering education and is probably closer to a PE (Professional Engineer) designation. _Draughtsman_ is indeed just _чертежник_.

Comment: "a person who draws and **designs** mechanical, structural or machine parts" - чертежник? I disagree.

Comment: The OP's definition of a draughtsman conflicts with those found in common dictionaries, where it does _not_ include the "design" part at all.

Comment: @AviGordon not *модельщик*, but *модельер*

Comment: *модельер* is a clothes designer. The profession I referred to was called *модельщик*.